# Open custom bootstrap modal with vanilla JavaScript on DoubleClick event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, double-click

I want to open custom bootstrap modal using data from an object when double clicked on an element.
How to do this using vanilla JavaScript.

Also how to add all functionalities in it :

- Ease Transition
- Modal should remove when clicked on cross or outside of body
- always clear the previous data(no caching)

https://jsfiddle.net/awo0hq4c/

**NOTE : Modal used is basic bootstrap modal which is given below but instead of button it is a div in my case**

````
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append this line of code into the last line of `showModal()` function.

```
new bootstrap.Modal(modalItem).show();
```

*https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript*

```js
 const div = document.querySelector('.container');

  div.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
    showModal({
      id: '1',
      title: 'Title Modal',
      value: 'this is modal content',
    });
  });

  const showModal = (data) => {
    console.log(data, 'here is');
    const modalItem = document.getElementById('exampleModal');

    modalItem.innerHTML = '';

    modalItem.innerHTML = ` <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">${data.title}</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                    ${data.value}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          `;

    new bootstrap.Modal(modalItem).show();
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Modal</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./modal.css"> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="exampleModal"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    ></div>

    <div class="btn btn-primary container">Launch modal</div>

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- <script src="./modal.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```